# Objective C PTP/IP connection

Tags: objective-c, tcp, camera, cfnetwork

I'd like to implement a "Picture Transfer Protocol over IP" (PTP/IP) connection with Objective C between my camera (Nikon D5300) and my Mac to transfer photos and other data wirelessly.

The camera creates a WiFi hotspot, and the Mac connects to it. 
I know that the camera uses port 15740.

What is the best point to start with? NSInputStream?

Comment: it's been a year and a half.. Did you implement??

Comment: nope, I am still having this question. Have you fond anything on this topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use CocoaAsyncSocket for communication. For communication, look at the PTP (over USB) spec and http://www.cipa.jp/ptp-ip/index_e.html. The payload packets are pretty much like in the USB spec but have some different header bytes.

Answer (score 2):

I know that ShutterSnitch has this (iOS app). I emailed its author, who while wasn't willing to license me his work, was very kind to point me to the following resources: 
http://www.shuttersnitch.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=1580